# Is code injection possible in the test string of a RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, code-injection

Is code injeciton possible in the test string of a JavaScript RegExp?

This code is executed server side:

```
const userInput = "..."; // user input provided by client
const match = new RegExp(regex, "i").test(userInput);
```

The `regex` is static and resides server side. Only the `userInput` string is what we have no control over, the user can enter whatever they want.

Is it possible for an attacker to inject code, or should this be safely handled by the JS `RegExp` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's safe unless there's a very specific vulnerability (buffer overrun, etc.) in the JavaScript engine running the regex, which is *very unlikely* but not completely impossible.

Answer (score 1):

`new RegExp(...).test(userInput)` is safe from injection vulnerabilities, but it is a denial of service vector (ReDoS).

["Reviewing Regexes in The Application"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/redos.html) explains how to vet the regexp that you got from the server.

Comment: In this case, the regex is static and server-side, only the test string is provided by the user.

Comment: Great article, thanks Mike, so you are referring to "make sure that your regexes won't exhibit catastrophic backtracking". Good point.

Comment: @Manuel, yep.  There's no greater risk of ReDoS for a RegExp written `/.../` instead of `new RegExp(...)` when the pattern isn't attacker controlled, so this may not really be relevant to your question.

Comment: How about `new RegExp(userInput).test(...)` ? Is that safe?

Comment: @Ellis, no.  Creating regular expressions from untrustworthy inputs is a textbook ReDoS vulnerability.  See https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS